# How can I access ansible facts of another server?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to access Ansible facts for a different host than my target host. Following is my sample playbook. But facts are not collected for `util` server when I run the below play. Can someone help me, how can I access facts of a different server?

```
---
- hosts: build
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
        dist: "{{  hostvars['util']['ansible_facts']['distribution'] }}"
  tasks:
     - name: Demo Magic variables
       debug:
           var: "{{ dist }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply gather the needed facts from your desired server prior to using them. The simplest solution:

```yaml
---
- name: Gather facts from util server
  hosts: util

- name: Do our job
  hosts: build
  vars:
    dist: "{{ hostvars['util']['ansible_facts']['distribution'] }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Demo Magic variables
      debug:
        var: "{{ dist }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Zeitounator... Your solution is working.